# Run AutoIT script in silent mode

Tags: scripting, autoit, silent

I have an AutoIT script that will automate all the system testing configurations in my company. It works fine without any user interaction however I am wondering if it will be possible to run in silent mode as the script contains quite a few mouseclicks.

Here is a code snippet:

```
Run("C:\AutoTestPackage\TestSuite\SmokeTest\WCF\Prerequisite\BISSDK\WcfClient.TestApp.exe")
_WinWaitCheck($WCFClient)
WinActivate($WCFClient)
WinMove($WCFClient, "", 64, 200, 1200, 600)
Sleep(1000)
    
MouseClick("", 400, 60, 1) ;Click on Username textbox
Sleep(250)
Send($OperatorName)
Sleep(500)
MouseClick("", 700, 60, 1) ;Click on Password textbox
Sleep(250)
Send($FinalOperatorPassword)
Sleep(1000)
    
MouseClick("", 1080, 50, 1) ;Click on Ping option
Sleep(1000)
    
MouseClick("", 70, 74, 1); Click on SynchronLogon
Sleep(1000)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: sorry, but I just *have*  to ask: what do you mean with "Silent mode"?

Comment: Have a look at ControlClick and ControlSend

Comment: @Xenobiologist Hi, sorry for the late response. I did try to change to ControlClick on some of the commands. However, it will not be possible for some of them as it involves clicking a specific tab.

Comment: @Stephan What I mean by silent mode is letting the computer go into sleep and when it wakes up, the script will still be executing the code.